# If $f(x_1...x_n)=g(x_1...x_{n-1})$ in the domain of $f$, is $f$ a function of $n$ or $n-1$ variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, terminology

I ask this question in generality because I want to understand in all situations.

If I define a function's domain $f$ so that it's $nth$ argument must always be a particular function of the other $n-1$ arguments. So for all points in $D$, $f(x_1...x_{n})=g(x_1...x_{n-1})$ which can be rewritten as a composite of a function $d(x_1...x_{n-1})$, that relates $(x_1...x_{n-1})$ to $(x_1...x_{n})$ and $f$, hence $x_n=h(x_1..x_{n-1})$ for some function $h$.

Knowing all this we can say that $f(X_{n})=d∘f(X_{n-1})$ (Notation re-written for simplicity).
If a function can be written as a composite of itself and another function, and hence as a function of $n-1$ variables due to it's domain, how do we describe the number of arguments that $f$ takes? Is it either $n$ or $n-1$?

Does the fact the function seems to have arity $n$ suggest we can describe it as a function of $n$ variables, but it can be described by $n-1$ values.

The definition of a multivariable function is one that is 'defined' on a subset of $R^n$ such  that there exists at least one 'non-empty open set', I'm not sure if $f$ in this case would have a domain containing an open set.

Comment: The domain of $f$ is $\Bbb R^n$, independent of any other considerations. A constant function (which depends on $0$ variables) still needs to know what its domain is.

Comment: Said differently: $f$ is a function that has $n$ slots, period. You may choose to put into the $n^{\textrm{th}}$ slot an expression formed from what you put into the prior $n-1$ slots, but that has nothing intrinsically to do with $f$. That's just how you are choosing to use $f$ in some particular circumstance.

Comment: @MPW so if I set the domain of $f$ to be {$(a,a), a∈R$} the fact that it maps through tuples of dimension '2' makes it a function of 'two variables' (in the n=2 case)

Comment: No. $f$ takes a single argument, which must be a point on the diagonal. It's an interesting fact that any such point can be uniquely described by a single real number, so most people would understand what you meant if you wrote a definition of $f$ as $f((a,a)) =  a^2$, for example, but $f$ is still a function of one variable.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC in this case would you say that the fact it can be defined by a single value makes it 'single variable' even though it seems like it's arity is two, I would tend to agree but I'm not sure, also do we use the partial derivative or standard derivative notation, as neither are really defined as $f$ only changes in the direction of the diagonal.

Comment: You get partial and standard derivatives automatically, "for free", when you are dealing with open subsets of some $\mathbb R ^n$. You've stepped away from that when you decided to make your domain the diagonal, so now you have to explicitly define the differentiable manifold structure on it.